# Criar arquivo com permissão de execução

Tags: linux, shell-script

Quando eu crio arquivo `.sh`, eu preciso dar permissão para ele ser executado, existe algum arquivo que possa ser configurado ou `comando` aplicado para que eu já possa criar o arquivo com a permissão de execução?

Comment: A única forma que conheço é `chmod +x filename.sh`

Comment: Porque, por linha de comando não crias ficheiros, abres e depois ao guardar é que são criados...

Comment: @JorgeB. Acredito que ele quer uma forma automatizada de fazer isso

Comment: Eu sei @MaiconCarraro, só que não estou a ver nenhuma, a não ser que seja um script para criar scripts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você usa *vim*, essa pode ser uma solução automatizada:

Adicione a linha seguinte no seu *~/.vimrc*:

```
au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | if getline(1) =~ "/bin/" | silent !chmod +x <afile> | endif | endif
```

Ela vai detectar sempre que houver um arquivo onde a primeira linha possua "/bin/" ou comece por "#!" e execuar o *chmod +x* automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível adicionar o privilégio de execução por padrão na criação de arquivos.

A configuração `umask` (*file-creation mode mask*) do sistema controla as permissões padrão de arquivos e diretórios. O valor padrão é 0002, que resulta nas permissões 0664 (666 - 002, `fmask` - `umask`) para arquivos e 0775 (777 - 002, `dmask` - `umask`) para diretórios. E não é possível alterar `fmask` e `dmask`.

Fonte: [Making new files automatically executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15599951/2932525)

---

A solução seria criar uma tarefa agendada utilizando o comando `crontab -e` e inserindo a linha abaixo no fim do arquivo

```
* * * * * find ~/*.sh -type f -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

O comando será executado a cada minuto, ele localiza os arquivos .sh dentro da sua pasta de usuário e adiciona permissões de execução.

Pode ser interessante executar a cada 5 minutos (ou mais), de acordo com usa demanda, para isso altere o início da linha para `*/5 * * * *`

Comment: Eu pensei nesta forma também.

Answer (score 1):

Se isso é algo comum para você, por que você não cria um comando para isso e salva no seu `Path` com seus `bin`? Tipo assim:

```
echo -e "#!"`which bash`"\ntouch \$1 && chmod +x \$1" > mkscript && chmod +x mkscript
```

Aí sempre que você quiser criar um script executável, é só vc chamar o comando assim:

```
mkscript <nome_script>
```